# Declaring mass amounts of class instances in c++

Tags: c++

I am taking an OS class and my goal for an assignment is comparing wait times for FCFS and SJF scheduling algorithms for 1000 processes. I am not actually creating 1000 processes, rather a table of  1000 random pid's, 1000 random arrival times, and 1000 random burst times, all with integer values. I realize this can easily be done by just creating 3 arrays and assigning 1000 rand() values to each array, but I also need to sort these by arrival time and burst time for the algorithms.

My question is, is there any way to make a class with these attributes, then declare 1000 instances of this class without having to individually declare all 1000 of them by hand? I know you cannot dynamically declare variables in c++, so if there is another way around this I would be very interested to know. Or, if there are any other solutions i.e. linking the arrays, etc. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Anything wrong with making a class and then declaring an array of that class? Seems the obvious thing to do.

Comment: Sounds like you just want custom `Process` struct and then a [`std::array<Process, 1000>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: When you say "you cannot dynamically declare variables in c++" I'm not sure what you mean. "Dynamic" just has a different meaning in C++ than in something interpreted.

Comment: @tadman I just mean that you cannot do something like use a for loop to declare int variables, as you cannot name a variable with the incrementing value. i.e. within a for loop you cannot declare "int new_integeri" or something along those lines. For one, the variable would be local to the for loop. But it would also be one integer with the name new_integeri and not various integers named new_integer(insert value of i here). Bad explanation but this is all I was trying to say.

Comment: You can't create variables with arbitrary names because once the code is compiled variables don't exist, they're only there for humans to read, so yeah, that's not practical. You can, however, use `std::map` or `std::vector` to organize your data. Having numerous variables with related names is usually a bad way to go about solving problems. Instead of `int num1` through `num100` you usually want `int num[100]`. If you want arbitrary labels, `std::map<std::string, int>` can do the trick.

Comment: I realize this is the way to go about it, I was originally saying this because I was trying to get around naming each class instance individually, as I know you cannot do it with something as simple as a for loop. It has been a while since I've used vectors and such and I forgot about using a vector of objects, as the answer below points out. I appreciate your response, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `std::vector<MyClass>` of your class objects. When you then initialize that, the default constructor will be called for each object in the vector (the number of which is given as the `size_t` argument). Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

static int dummy = 0;
class MyClass {
public:
    int test;
    MyClass() : test(dummy+=2) { 
        std::cout << "Constructor called!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    size_t n;
    std::cout << "How many objects? ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<MyClass> MyObjects(n); // Creates 'n' new objects and initializes them
    for (auto obj : MyObjects) {
        std::cout << obj.test << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you know how many objects you have in your list *at compile time*, you can use `std::array` in place of `std::vector`:

```cpp
    std::array<MyClass, 10> MyObjects;
```

Comment: If you did this in my case, would the values for the integer attributes be initialized to 0 like they would in a normal integer array?

Comment: @tcolbert That would depend on what you did with your default constructor. I used the static variable and a concocted constructor to give a hint of what you *could* do, but almost anything is possible, with proper thought/design.